# How to install wkhtmltopdf Libraries?

Tags: drupal-views

Drupal 7.59 / Civi 4.7.27

I use Views extensively, and would like to add https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_pdf module.

As per the Module documentation, a prerequisite is the installation of wkhtmltopdf Library (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which should result in the following structure :

- sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf
- sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf/scr
- sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf/scr/Pdf.php

But I don't find those files in the wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz dowload, especially no Pdf.php

I am not a programmer, and thus not familiar with Libraries installation : any help would be welcome

Comment: Hi Jacques - since this is not a civicrm question i would suggest you ask it in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Pete, yes of course, but it was just in case someone here would know

Comment: fyi we often just use the Print module for PDF buttons on Views displays

Comment: Thank you Pete : I just installed https://www.drupal.org/project/printfriendly : but I can't have the button on a View Page (I have it only on Pages (without Views) and Webforms) : what did I miss ?

Comment: i meant drupal.org/project/print - it works for Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pete says, not really a Civi question ... but since it is here:

I think there is a typo in the installation instructions at https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_pdf

The first step reads:

> Place WkHtmlToPdf library under ...

but should be:

> Place phpwkhtmltopdf library under ...

phpwkhtmltopdf provides the php files you listed, not WkHtmlToPdf

Note also that 'scr' in the file list should be 'src'